# Extracting function name from boost stacktrace

Tags: c++, stack-trace

I use boost stacktrace to dump a stacktrace when an application crashes. The final version of the application will be stripped which means there is no function name information available.

The dump file writing happens as follows:

```
static void segmentationFaultHandler(int signo) {
    std::signal(signo, SIG_DFL);
    boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("./backtrace.dump");
    std::raise(SIGABRT);
}
```

This writes a dump file an the next application start will write a readable stacktrace with addresses as text file somewhere. This works so far but function name extraction seems to be impossible because the final binary is stripped. The binary is compiled with PIE option.

Is it possible to get information on the function name when I have the address from the stacktrace and the unstripped binary?

Comment: gdb [info symbol addr](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Symbols.html) _Print the name of a symbol which is stored at the address addr_ Should do the job.

Comment: I tried that but the result is that no symbol matches. I experimented with an expected assert which dumps a stacktrace and the address is always different when I rerun the program.